# Mejorar el performance entre cambio de tabs usando fragments y recyclerview an android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación para llevar el control de un álbum de stickers cuando cambio a faltantes aparecen en el fragment faltantes y se actualizan cuando selecciono o deselecciono algún número. El tema es que tengo que estar recargando la info entre tags y se alenta cuando recargo el adaptador del RecyclerView y crea todos los elementos. ¿Cómo puedo mejorar este rendimiento?

Utilizo la siguiente función para recrear los fragmentos cuando cambio de tabs pero es necesario porque actualizo la base cuando selecciono un ítem y debe refrescarse para ver los cambios entre tabs,

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    //Fragment newFragment = new Fragment();
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser ) {
        //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.recyclerFaltantes,newFragment).commit();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La idea cuando manejas tabs, es que el adapter se ecargue de controlar como se muestran los fragments en pantalla. Lo que hace este adapter es crear los fragments que se van a mostrar y mantenerlos de tal forma que no sea necesario crearlos y destruirlos periodicamente. Con esto en mente, lo que haces cuando usas las lineas de codigo

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Estas gastando memoria cuando no hay necesidad de hacerlo. Si lo que deseas es actualizar la informacion en tu segundo fragment debes hacerlo de tal forma que no debas eliminar y despues volver a renderizar la vista.

Lo que te recomiendo es implementar un metodo en el fragment que se encargue de cambiar cambiar la informacion que se muestra en el fragment y llamar dicho metodo usando el listener que ya tienes implementando para detectar que un fragment se muestra en pantalla.

Espero esta respuesta sea de ayuda.